# Convert unicode string to an escaped ASCII string with '%XX' characters

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

I have java code that gets URLs with UTF characters, that should be converted to "escaped" characters, such as `%A4%FD` etc.

Is there a way to make this conversion?

Comment: Yes there is. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, @MadPhysicist, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at java.net.URLEncoder. Or you can make your own encoder based on String.format:

```
char c = 'Ë';
String hex = System.out.printf("%%%02X%%%02X", c & 0xFF, (c >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

this converts c to `%CB%00`

To covert a string:

```
    String s = "1Ë2";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c > 128) {
            sb.append(String.format("%%%02X%%%02X", c & 0xFF, (c >> 8) & 0xFF));
        } else if (c == '%'){
            sb.append("%%");
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

result:

```
1%CB%002
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with `URLEncoder` is that it also encodes the `:` and `/` characters, that I want to keep as they are. I only want to convert non-ASCII characters to their escaped version

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:URLEncoder.encode(str2, "utf-8")